# Debugging PHP on remote Turnkey Linux LAMP server in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, xdebug, lamp, turnkeylinux.org

I've been trying to get debugging working in VS Code for hours and have read every tutorial and question and answer, but no luck.

I have a server using Turnkey Linux LAMP with PHP 7.4 and Xdebug 3.

On another Windows computer I have VS Code running and am trying to debug.

I have tried various settings, but currently VS Code `launch.json` looks like this?

```json
{
    "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
    "type": "php",
    "request": "launch",
    "port": 9003,
    "hostname": "192.168.20.110",
    "pathMappings": {
        "/var/websites/test": "${workspaceFolder}/",
    }
}
```

On the server, `php.ini` looks like this, although I have tried various:

```ini
[xdebug]
xdebug.mode=develop,debug
xdebug.discover_client_host=1
xdebug.client_port = 9003
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
```

Whenever I press the run button in VS Code I get

> listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available 192.168.20.110:9003

I have tried creating a firewall exception on the server for port 9003.

I have installed Xdebug extension in Chrome.

What am I missing?

Comment: *"`"hostname": "192.168.20.110",`"* I do not think you need this at all. Just in case: It's Xdebug that connects to the debug client (VS Code in your case) and NOT other way around. 1) Enabled Xdebug log (must point to a file, writable) -- it will show where it tries to connect to (if at all) and what the response is. 2) Check your `xdebug_info();` output -- it will show all live/actual config values + some debug messages. 3) Make sure you are checking the config/setup in the same environment .. as it's very common to have one php.ini for web server and one for CLI on Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First definitely remove the `hostname` setting from `launch.json`. This is the IP the IDE tries to bind to and as this is a remote IP of the server it cannot. Also do not use `localhost` as then the server will not be able to communicate with the workstation.

Path mappings could be wrong as you did not provide information how the workstation is accessing the files on the server (SMB, SSH, SFTP).

I suggest adding `xdebug_info();` in one of the php files that you open with a browser and see what output it generates.

Comment: I have removed hostname from launch.json. The workstation needs access to the files on the server? I don't think I have done that part. I will try and work out that then. Thanks.

Comment: Added SFTP VS Code extension and cofigured and debug started working